# Batch file: Deleting folders after for loop

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, delete-file

This is what i have right now. If I run this script, loop never ends and run forever. 
I tried to delete a folder in kmz folder after moving a file inside kmz folder's folder; however, it wont delete a folder inside the kmz folder. I think this is why my batch file is running forever. 
any help??

```
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion


:loop
IF EXIST D:\kmz\*.* (
    FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /b /s /a-d "D:kmz\*.*" ') do (
        FOR %%b IN ("%%~dpa.") do (
            REN "%%a" "%%~nb.*"
            move %%b\* D:\renamed
            del %%b 
            goto loop2
            )
        )
)

:loop2
IF EXIST D:\renamed\*.* (
    for /R D:\renamed %%G in (*.*) do (
        ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" "D:\shapefile\%%~nG_boundary.shp" "%%G"
        move %%G D:\Photos\%%~nG
        goto transfering 
        )
)

:transfering 
IF EXIST D:\shapefile\*.shp (
    for /R D:\shapefile %%K in (*.*) do (
        set "filename=%%~nK"
        set "first5=!filename:~0,5!"
        move %%K D:\Photos\!first5!
        echo !date!-!time! %%K is created >> D:\Photos\!first5!\log.txt
        )
) 

goto loop
```

this is my second try:

```
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion


:loop
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /b /s /a-d "D:kmz\*.*" ') do (
        FOR %%b IN ("%%~dpa.") do (
            IF EXIST %%a (
            REN "%%a" "%%~nb.*"
            move %%b\* D:\renamed
            rmdir %%~dpa
            goto loop2
            )
        )
)

:loop2
IF EXIST D:\renamed\*.* (
    for /R D:\renamed %%G in (*.*) do (
        ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" "D:\shapefile\%%~nG_boundary.shp" "%%G"
        move %%G D:\Photos\%%~nG
        goto transfering 
        )
)

:transfering 
IF EXIST D:\shapefile\*.shp (
    for /R D:\shapefile %%K in (*.*) do (
        set "filename=%%~nK"
        set "first5=!filename:~0,5!"
        move %%K D:\Photos\!first5!
        echo !date!-!time! %%K is created >> D:\Photos\!first5!\log.txt
        )
) 

goto loop
```

I was able to delete a folder from D:\kmz, but loops wont stop.
I this this output is the reason...

```
C:\>FOR /F "delims=" %a IN ('dir /b /s /a-d "D:kmz\*.*" ') do (FOR %b IN ("%~dpa.") do (IF EXIST %a (
REN "%a" "%~nb.*"
 move %b\* D:\renamed
 rmdir %~dpa
 goto loop2
) ) )
File Not Found
```

Comment: What do you mean by the loops won't stop. You are aware that you've written `goto loop` at the bottom, so that as soon as your script ends it starts again, aren't you?

Comment: BTW, you have a missing backslash in your path within the for loop command, `D:kmz` should clearly be `D:\kmz`. _(You've even repeated the typo when copying it to your bottom example too!)_

Comment: I want to run this script when there is any folder in the D:\kmz folder. When there is no folder, i want this script to wait until new folders come in this D:\kmz folder. But right now, when there is no more folder in D:\kmz, no file found output keeps showing up on cmd output.

Answer (score 0):

To stop your loop, try setting loop as a variable with a value of one, and code it so that every time you run the command it takes away one from loop. Then say if the loop variable equals 0, go to another part which has the directory of your file and the delete command. I hope this works.